# Render Components from Array loop

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

In my app.component.ts I have an array with the component tags.

```
compData = ['app-component-one', 'app-component-two', 'app-component-three'];
```

Then in my app.component.html I have this:

```
<div *ngFor="let comps of compData">

    // I tried this: {{comps}} but that will not render the components

</div>
```

How can I do this so I can render each component?

Comment: did you try `<{{comps}}></{{comps}}>` ?

Comment: @JiiB, do you really think, it would work?

Comment: You cannot do that

Comment: https://ng-run.com/edit/Wr9FbuZHJnkTbFxahBtE

Comment: @Qwertiy no i'm not sure at all. But normally you write your component tag like a normal opening and closing html tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot render components from array, instead you need to look at dynamic component generator

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader