# Angular/typescript load component from variable

Tags: angular, typescript

How can i load compontent from variable?
Etc. I have an array

```
let arr: Array<string> = new Array('<comp1></comp1>','<comp2></comp2>');
```

in my html temple walk array, and get compontent, but only i see string as ''

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of arr">{{item}}</ngcontainer>
```

thanks for answers.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525649/render-components-from-array-loop

Answer (score 2):

You would need an array of types rather than of strings:

```
const types: ReadonlyArray<Type> = new Array(Comp1Class, Comp2Class);
```

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let componentTypeExpression of types">
  <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="componentTypeExpression"></ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Keep in mind they all must be in `entryComponents` of injector. For lazy modules you can add injector or even customize module factory:
https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer, but my array in a service in deep. I cant import every item in array. if i call simply <compontent></compontent> in html is work. But i call *ngComponentOutlet="'ClassName'" is not working...

Comment: This is how you do it in Angular, you would have to refactor your service then, because even if you find some black magic that does what you ask, it would still be dark magic. Here's an Angular library that works with templates in React way by writing HTML in JS as strings, maybe it could help you:
https://blog.angularindepth.com/introducing-to-ng-vdom-a-new-way-to-write-angular-application-60a3be805e59